# Codeigniter get data from other web service

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I've API that builds with rails to post and get data, this service used in android, and I will use this service in my web apps with CodeIgniter to.

It's possible to post and get data using another web services in CodeIgniter? I search anything just found create restful API using CodeIgniter not get/post data using another web service in CI.

I've using ajax to handle my get and post data and this code placed in Views but I don't think it's secure and in Edge my ajax function sometimes doesn't work well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe it can help you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814